# MySQL: Convert year-by-year rows to columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble accomplishing something with a MySQL select query.  I have a table of statistics consisting of an alphanumeric ID column, a yearID column, and then a number of various other columns indicating how many times something occurred in the indicated year.  Like this:

```
personID  yearID  event1  event2  event3
person1     1999      12      15       2
person1     2000      14       7       3
person1     2001      25      10       2
person2     1999      16      12       1
person2     2000      15      14       1
person2     2001       9      20       2
```

I'm trying to use select to get the following columns:

```
personID  event1_1999  event1_2000 event1_2001 event2_1999 event2_2000   etc...
```

and so I used this type of code:

```
select
personID,
if(year_ID = "1999",event1,NULL) AS event1_1999,
if(year_ID = "2000",event1,NULL) AS event1_2000,
if(year_ID = "2000",event1,NULL) AS event1_2001,
etc.
```

What I found in the results, unforunately, is that only the columns corresponding to the first year (so, in the example, event1_1999, event2_1999, etc) contain any data, the rest are all null.  I can't figure out why this is, or a way to work around it.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: This is a common type of question, search SO for "mysql pivot". You'll find lots of them.

Comment: Thanks - I see a technique for getting this done now, but I don't yet get why my technique failed. Any insight there?

Comment: @JohnC: You haven't posted your technique, so that's impossible to answer: the reason your technique failed will depend on what your technique *was*. (For example, did your query use `GROUP BY`? With or without `GROUP BY`, either way would fail, but for different reasons.) If you post a *complete* query that uses your technique, you have a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: My bad, and thanks for the advice - this is my first post here.  I can't post the whole query, as it's over 1000 lines, but the relevant part was that I used group by personID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *...I see a technique for getting this done now, but **I don't yet get why my technique failed**. Any insight there?...*

You have to use an aggregate function (`SUM()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()` depending on your needs) and `GROUP BY`

Try

```
SELECT personid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yearID = 1999 THEN event1 ELSE 0 END) event1_1999,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yearID = 2000 THEN event1 ELSE 0 END) event1_2000,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yearID = 2001 THEN event1 ELSE 0 END) event1_2001
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY personid
```

Same thing but with `IF`

```
SELECT personid,
       SUM(IF(yearID = 1999, event1, 0)) event1_1999,
       SUM(IF(yearID = 2000, event1, 0)) event1_2000,
       SUM(IF(yearID = 2001, event1, 0)) event1_2001
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY personid
```

Output in both cases

```
| PERSONID | EVENT1_1999 | EVENT1_2000 | EVENT1_2001 |
------------------------------------------------------
|  person1 |          12 |          14 |          25 |
|  person2 |          16 |          15 |           9 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68d8a/3)** demo

**UPDATE** To get `NULL`s in case of absent data

```
SELECT personid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yearID = 1999 THEN event1 END) event1_1999,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yearID = 2000 THEN event1 END) event1_2000,
       SUM(CASE WHEN yearID = 2001 THEN event1 END) event1_2001
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY personid;

SELECT personid,
       SUM(IF(yearID = 1999, event1, NULL)) event1_1999,
       SUM(IF(yearID = 2000, event1, NULL)) event1_2000,
       SUM(IF(yearID = 2001, event1, NULL)) event1_2001
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY personid;
```

Sample output:

```
| PERSONID | EVENT1_1999 | EVENT1_2000 | EVENT1_2001 |
------------------------------------------------------
|  person1 |          12 |          14 |          25 |
|  person2 |          16 |          15 |           9 |
|  person3 |           3 |      (null) |      (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bad14/1)** demo

Comment: So, the lack of an aggregator was the problem, then. I was already using group by personID, but failed to mention it.  Zero is a possibility for some of the values - would NULL work on either example you used?

Comment: Sorry - I got sent out to run errands shortly after posting my initial question, so I haven't had a chance to try it yet.  I also got autocorrected on my previous comment, so here's what I meant to ask: some of the values from the original table could potentially be zero, so having zero as an outcome of the if or case statements won't work.  Can I use NULL instead?  If not, I think I'll need to use some outrageously, impossibly large value instead.

Comment: Just tried it, and it worked!  Thanks, and I'll accept the answer as soon as I figure out how.